# CORS with SPServices + jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sharepoint, spservices

I need to access from a different domaine on a mobile a sharepoint list. Here is my code, a simple get request :

```
$.support.cors = true;

$(function() {
$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    webURL: "http://myurl.com/project/",
    listName: "PM-Registration",
    CAMLQuery: '<Query></Query>',
    error: function (xhr, message, error) {
          alert('error : ' + error);
    },
    completefunc: function (xData, status) {
        alert('Status: '+status+' xdata: ' + xData.statusText);
        alert('RESPONSE: ' + xData.responseText);
    }
});
});
```

The problem seems to be CORS blocking the request, but I normally enable it before.
It works perfectly with Chrome if I use the command : --args --disable-web-security, and with Safari desktop, but not with Firefox and Safari iOS...
I got the error on Chrome without disabling web security :

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

Am I missing something ? I guess it is a client side problem as it works with Chrome without web security and Safari Desktop

Comment: I am getting same error, are you able to find any solution, It works perfectly in IE but not in other browsers.

Comment: I will provide an answer to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will provide an answer to my question.

Even if it work on IE and with specific command on Chrome, this is a security issue set on the server side, only the server can change it by modifing the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`

I didn't find a workaround to avoid this CORS problem from the client side. My solution was to move my HTML page on the same domain as my SharePoint. I have now my SharePoint : `www.mysharepoint.com`, and my mobile webapp `www.mysharepoint.com/mobile/index.html`

Comment: thank you for your reply, My client has 2 site collections, first is main portal http://portal.com.au and second is http://new.portal.com.au and looks like it is not possible.